# Is there a way to have registered users auto-publish their articles

Tags: articles, workflow

I'm extremely new to Joomla and even simply hosting a website, so answers should be pretty step-by-step if possible.

I am running a hobby group site that will have multiple users submitting articles to it.

Ideally, I'd like registered users to be able to post their own articles without needing approval. So I'd like them to have publishing rights to their own articles. I would like them to be able to have the ability to edit the state of their own article, but NOT be able to edit the state of another users's articles.

I had it set up to where users were able to auto-publish their own articles by turning on the "edit state" for them. However that made them able to unpublish other users articles. Not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the component User Article Manager (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-submission/18412). It has lot's of options and settings to fine-tune what your users can and cannot do.

By creating a menu item for each user group, and give them permission to edit/publish their own articles only.

**NOTE:** User Article Manager: This extension has been unpublished for the following reason:

```
UR3: Vulnerable Extension
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using an extension to do what I wanted. It has worked like a charm. I still feel like I'm missing something obvious in the core Joomla abilities, but I have been reading and working on this for two days, so if an extension gets it done, ah well!

https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-submission/user-article-manager

**Note:** *This extension was reported as vulverable, therefore it has been removed from JED*

Answer (score 0):

Joomla supports this fully. There are already several levels of access set up in the default installation, but you can create your own levels and tweak the ACL (Access Control List) settings to your hearts content (including changing the settings for 3rd party components).

Here's a short tutorial that might shed some light:
http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Access_Control_List_Tutorial

"Edit Own" is the setting you'll want to pay the most attention to. They can then flip the published/unpublished on their own articles.

Comment: If logged in as a "Registered" user, and with "Edit Own" but "Edit State" turned off in global settings, I can change the text and edit the content of my articles. I cannot publish or unpublish, even my own article. I want to be able to publish my own articles. If I then go to turn on "Edit State" with "Edit Own" turned on, I can publish/unpublish--but I can do that for ANY article. I seem to be missing a key point somewhere. I guess, I'd like to have a default "publish" setting for my "registered" users, and an "Edit Own" turned on. I'm on Joomla 3.3.3.

Comment: I think the issue is probably that you were just using Registered as the ACL group. I think if you switch them to Editor instead, it'll give them more privileges. Or you could edit the ACL for the Registered group and tweak the settings. I'm not home (I'm actually at Disney World) or I'd do some testing of my own.

Answer (score 0):

JoomlaShack has an extension:
https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/shack-article-manager/

Comment: Please add some additional information, telling why and how this extension can help the OP solve his problem.

Comment: @Bjørn Thanks for joining us.  Please more a bit more generous with your recommendation.  There are often times when a pre-existing extension can resolve a problem, but if everyone just dropped a link to the JED in these occasions, then this community would be effectively a traffic-routing community.  Please explain why you feel this particular extension is advisable.  If there are any warnings/caveats/features that you would especially like to mention, this would be very valuable to the OP and future researchers. Also, perhaps introduce yourself by editing your profile.